# Button not responding to OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-button

I have a `activity` that loads data from server. If the error occurs I show a `Button` to reload/retry for loading data. But the `onClickListener` does not respond when I click the button. Can someone please help me with this?

> This is my activity

```
public class MyContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ContactsAdapter adapter;
    private NetworkChecker networkChecker;
    private SessionManager sessionManager;
    private AppConfig appConfig;
    private RelativeLayout loading, retry;
    private Button tryAgain;
    AlertHelper alertHelper;
    final ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_contacts);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        loading = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel);
        retry = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.retry);
        tryAgain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tryAgainButton);

        alertHelper = new AlertHelper(this);
        networkChecker = new NetworkChecker(this);
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        appConfig = new AppConfig();

        String phone = sessionManager.getLoggedInUserPhone();
        url = appConfig.getApiUrlForSpecificContacts(phone);

        tryAgain.setOnClickListener(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.contactsView);
        adapter = new ContactsAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        sendJsonRequest(url);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone);
                        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactProfileActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("selected_user_phone", phone.getText());
                        i.putExtra("selected_user_name", name.getText());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
        );

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void sendJsonRequest(String url) {
        if (networkChecker.networkAvailable()) {
            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getmRequestQueue();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    retry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        if(jsonArray != null){
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject currentContact = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String name = currentContact.getString("name");
                                String phone = currentContact.getString("phone");
                                String city = currentContact.getString("city");
                                String address = currentContact.getString("address");
                                Boolean verified = currentContact.getBoolean("verified");

                                Contact contact = new Contact(name, phone, city, address, verified);

                                contactArrayList.add(contact);

                            }
                            adapter.setContactsList(contactArrayList);
                        }
                        else{
                            alertHelper.displayDialog("No Contacts Found.");
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        alertHelper.displayDialog(getString(R.string.connection_failed));
                    } else {
                        alertHelper.displayDialog(error.toString());
                    }
                }
            });

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        } else {
            alertHelper.displayDialog(getString(R.string.network_not_available));
            retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.tryAgainButton:
                sendJsonRequest(url);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> And this is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.pinesofts.quickcontact.MyContactsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/retry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retryText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/try_again_text"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tryAgainButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/retryText"
                android:text="Try Again"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_my_contacts" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: attach screenshot @Lalit

Comment: try adding clickable true when you make your button visible

Comment: which screenshot are we talking about @JigneshMavani

Comment: That didn't help either @VivekMishra

Comment: How do you know it's not responding? Did you set a break point in `onClick()`? Did you add a log print there?

Comment: can you please put log on your sendJsonRequest method . all looks fine from above code

Comment: <include layout="@layout/content_my_contacts" /> try to button in below

Comment: Print toast here `sendJsonRequest(url);`

Comment: Toast is not showing @IntelliJAmiya and the button click is simply not responding anything

Comment: Where have you assigned a URL to the string?

Comment: @MikeM. I printed log messages on my `onClick` but nothing is printed so I figured it does not reached there.

Comment: whats the value in variable url

Comment: Hi...
Add this in your xml of button : setClickable="true".
And,after setting the visibility of your relative view in error,
bring that layout to front,by : yourlayout.bringToFront(); method.
Hope it can help....

Comment: @AditiParikh I already figured this out. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out guys. Thanks to your comments and suggestions.

In the `layout file` above what I was doing is using `LinearLayout` with `height` and `width` as `match_parent` to wrap my two `RelativeLayout` and leaving `include` outside of `LinearLayout`.

My `include` file contains `RecyclerView` which also has `match_parent` on both `height` and `width`.

Due to this `RecyclerView` was on top of my `RelativeLayout` which contains my `Button`. So I was not even able to click my `Button`.

I changed my `xml` file as below and it's working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.pinesofts.quickcontact.MyContactsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/retry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retryText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/try_again_text"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tryAgainButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:text="Try Again"
                android:layout_below="@+id/retryText"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_my_contacts" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Ohhh . Glad to see that . Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

In you xml file add this line to your button  android:onClick="onClick", where onClick in the double quotes is the name of the method in your activity that will be called when the button is clicked.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/tryAgainButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/retryText"
            android:text="Try Again"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

There are two methods for calling the buttons, either call it with Listener or call the button directly from xml by writing a line in button's xml i.e android:onClick="the name of the method"

you are calling the button method here with the name 'onClick'

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tryAgainButton:
            sendJsonRequest(url);
            break;
    }
}
```

I also suggest you change the method name to any other name and define that name in the onClick statement of xml.

Comment: yes onClick is the name of the method but he is not defining the name in the xml, which is a second way to call the button.

Comment: ok write a log statement inside the button method. Log.e("btn clicked","yes"); and check whether this line is getting printed on clicking the button

Comment: @LalitThapa  try calling your button method directly and remove switch case

Answer (score 1):

> You can also define the onClick method in xml when declaring the
>   button (or any other clickable) component. When doing so, you have to
>   declare the method you want as the onClick method. For example, as you
>   can see, I’ve added an android:onClick attribute with value
>   clickFuncTion.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/tryAgainButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickFuncTion"
        android:text="Try Again" />
```

Then

```
public void clickFuncTion(View view){

    Toast.makeText(MyContactsActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // Add your staff
 }
```

Comment: Actually the problem is that the button is not even responding to click event so I guess this is not a solution.

Comment: @LalitThapa Let me confirm , When you used this approach ., Toast firing or not ?

Comment: @LalitThapa You should add Break Point

Comment: @LalitThapa Please comment your code . Follow #Richard Le Mesurier's approach . Hope this helps .

Comment: Move forward. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

you may try using and check if its working

```
tryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
  public void onClick(View v){

  sendJsonRequest(url);

}

});
```

Comment: It might happen that your button is under any view thats why its not able to identify the click..... Try changing the position of button and check if its working.

Comment: You can see my `xml layout` and how everything is placed. Can you suggest me how I can manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your `MyContactsActivity` code and my test version is working perfectly.

---

I commented out your `alertHelper`, `networkChecker`, `sessionManager`, `appConfig` because I do not have access to that code.

I also commented out all the setting up of your `recyclerView`.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_contacts);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        retry = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.retry);
        tryAgain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tryAgainButton);

//        alertHelper = new AlertHelper(this);
//        networkChecker = new NetworkChecker(this);
//        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
//        appConfig = new AppConfig();

//        String phone = sessionManager.getLoggedInUserPhone();
//        url = appConfig.getApiUrlForSpecificContacts(phone);

        tryAgain.setOnClickListener(this);

//        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.contactsView);
//        adapter = new ContactsAdapter(getApplicationContext());
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        String url = "unused";
        sendJsonRequest(url);
//        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

//        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
//                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
//                        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone);
//                        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
//                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactProfileActivity.class);
//                        i.putExtra("selected_user_phone", phone.getText());
//                        i.putExtra("selected_user_name", name.getText());
//                        startActivity(i);
//                    }
//                })
//        );

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

---

I changed your `sendJsonRequest` to just unhide the layout, and the `onClick` to show a `Toast`.

```
    private void sendJsonRequest(String url) {
        retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//        switch (v.getId()) {
//            case R.id.tryAgainButton:
//                sendJsonRequest(url);
//                break;
//        }
    }
```

---

The button works perfectly in this trimmed down code.

I suggest trying this code, and then adding each commented line back bit by bit as that will make it easy to find the issue.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for your effort.